# page is not getting displayed in my app view

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to load my facebook page in my Web View, but it's showing error 
when I made it load through chromo it displays. Here is my code;

```
var  mywebview: WebView =  findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView1)
var webSettings: WebSettings = mywebview.getSettings()
mywebview.setWebViewClient( WebViewClient())
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
webSettings.userAgentString
//  myWebView.setWebViewClient( WebViewClient())
mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/769268423274829/feed")
```

message of error but removing mywebview.setWebViewClient( WebViewClient())
let it open via Chromo without an error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
use this line of  code


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </uses-permission>



 WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Facebook link works (in Google Chrome for me) and you have the permission set for internet access, attach a listener to your WebView and see what it prints out.

```
var mywebview: WebView =  findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView1)
var webSettings: WebSettings = mywebview.getSettings()
mywebview.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView, errorCode: Int, description: String, failingUrl: String) {
            Log.e("CLASS NAME", errorCode.toString())
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl)
        }
    })
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
webSettings.userAgentString
mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/769268423274829/feed")
```

[Here is some more information (and a nice example with error handling and progress meter) on WebViews.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView)